# Error: "failed to connect to lvmetad" in Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: ubuntu, boot, gnome, lvm

My computer has a error that is preventing it from booting to the desktop. The error message is

> Warning failed to connect to lvmetad no such file or directory falling
>   back to internal scanning

It happened right after I installed GNOME, how to fix the error?